# Java - Getting compile error incompatible types int can't be converted to [][]

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

Having trouble understanding compile error. Main should be left unchanged. I believe `MakeandFillMatix` method is the problem and I can't figure it out. I think it's how I created the method.

```
import java.util.*;
/*

*/
public class TesterProject
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        int n = getMatrixSize();
        int[][] m = makeAndFillMatrix(n);
        printMatrix(m);
    }
    public static int getMatrixSize()
    {
        Scanner S = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("give me a int to create the matrix");
        int n = S.nextint();
        return n;
    }
    public static void makeAndFillMatrix(int [][] r)
    {
        Random generator = new Random(5);
        int rand = generator.nextInt(10);
        for(int i = 0; i < r.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < r; j++)
            {
                r[i][j]= rand;
            }
        }
        return r;
    }
    public static void printMatrix(int [][] matrix)
    {
        for(int r = 0; r < matrix.length; r++)
        {
            for(int c = 0; c < matrix[r].length; c++)
            {
                System.out.print(matrix[r][c] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Knowing the line number of the error would allow you to delete 95% of the code, and then someone might help you solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

You have many problems in your code :

1. `int n = S.nextint();` it should be `int n = S.nextInt();` with Upper I
2. You can't compare an int with an array `for (int j = 0; j < r; j++) {` i think you need this `for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {`
3. `void makeAndFillMatrix(int[][] r)` it not return any thing, and your return an array in the end.
4. `makeAndFillMatrix(int[][] r)` take an array of 2D and not an int `int[][] m = makeAndFillMatrix(n);`

Fix this problem and your problem is solve :)

---

**EDIT**

Then you have to change your code to be like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = getMatrixSize();
    int[][] m = makeAndFillMatrix(n);//<<<----Problem 4
    printMatrix(m);
}

public static int getMatrixSize() {
    Scanner S = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("give me a int to create the matrix");
    int n = S.nextInt();//<<--------------Problem 1
    return n;
}

public static int[][] makeAndFillMatrix(int n) {//<<<---Problem 3
    Random generator = new Random(5);
    int[][] r = new int[n][n];
    int rand = generator.nextInt(10);
    for (int i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {//<<<-----------Problem 2
            r[i][j] = rand;
        }
    }
    return r;
}

public static void printMatrix(int[][] matrix) {
    for (int r = 0; r < matrix.length; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < matrix[r].length; c++) {
            System.out.print(matrix[r][c] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: 4. I need to keep main the same. As it's my instructor code.

Comment: ok then your method should take an int and return a matrix, check my edit i put all the code @IDK

Comment: Wow, it works!!! Thank you and the other users for the help! Had to change for loop in the j to j  < r[i].length;

Comment: you are welcome @IDK

Answer (score 0):

Change `makeAndFillMatrix(int[][] r)` to `makeAndFillMatrix(int r)`
You want the matrix size, which is an integer, so take integer instead of a multidimensional array.

And in the for loop after that, change `r.length` to just `r`

Change `void` to `int [][]` in the method declaration.

In the method add a line `int[][] q;` and change `r[i][j] = rand` to `q[i][j] = rand`

And change `return r` to `return q`

Comment: Still get the same compile error after changing both.

Comment: I'm getting compile error q might have not been initialized.

Comment: Write int [][] q = new int[r][r];

Comment: Did it help? These are the only problems.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to cast 'int' (in the main function) to an 'int[][]' (the parameter of 'makeAndFillMatrix'. Also, makeAndFillMatrix returns 'void'.

I believe you want to rewrite your function to something like this:

```
public static int[][] makeAndFillMatrix(int r)
{
    // Create a new matrix
    int[][] matrix = new int[r][r];
    // Get a random value
    Random generator = new Random(5);
    int rand = generator.nextInt(10);
    // Assign random value to each cell of the matrix
    for(int i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < r; j++)
        {
            r[i][j] = rand;
        }
    }
    // Return the matrix
    return matrix;
}
```

Comment: after inputting that code I got a compiler error that says incompatible types: int[][] cannot be converted to int
  int matrix = new int[r][r];

Comment: Oh, my bad! You have to use int[][] matrix = new int[r][r] ! I'll update my answer!

Answer (score 0):

The error you are receiving is due to you calling

```
int[][] m = makeAndFillMatrix(n);
```

in your main method.

You set `n` as an `int` in the line above, meaning n is a number, BUT, `makeAndFillMatrix(int[][])` takes in a 2d array of `int`s. (A 2d array is a matrix, by the way.)

If you want to make a matrix of the size entered in by the user, then instead of passing `n` into your `makeAndFillMatrix` method, you would need to pass in a *matrix* of *size `n`*. You can do this in two ways. Option 1 is to pass in the matrix to your `makeAndFillMatrix` method like so:

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    int n = getMatrixSize();
    int[][] m = makeAndFillMatrix(new int[n][n]); // new int matrix of size n
    printMatrix(m);
}
```

Or (the more conventional way, in my opinion), you can give `makeAndFillMatrix` the size of the matrix (like you are doing), and you can have `makeAndFillMatrix` make the array:

```
public static void makeAndFillMatrix(int matrixSize)
{
    int[][] r = new int[matrixSize][matrixSize];
    Random generator = new Random(5);
    int rand = generator.nextInt(10);
    for(int i = 0; i < r.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < r[i].length; j++) //~~~I modified this line as well~~~
        {
            r[i][j]= rand;
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```

Anyways, you can take your pick at which approach you want to take to this problem, but **regardless, I noticed that your `makeAndFillMatrix` method had an error.** I fixed it and wrote `//~~~I modified this line as well~~~`

Your inner for loop originally said `for(int j = 0; j < r; j++)`, but `r` is a matrix. For the inner loop, you would want to increase `j` until it has reached the size of *the current row you are on in the matrix*, so I changed that line as well. (Your inner loop was correct in your `printMatrix` method.) Whichever approach you take for your first issue, the inner loop in your `makeAndFillMatrix` method will need to be modified as well.

I hope this helps!